# Android AsyncTask null

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to do an "loggin" based on qr scanner. What the task code do is to return an text wich is the name of the user, but I get this error. Anybody can help me?

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
JSONObject usuario;
static String resultadoqr;
public String texto;
private ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Modifica el layaout para q sea de pantalla completa
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //Se Inicia la view del layout
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    //Activa la progres bar
    pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}
public String devuelveusuario(){
    return texto;
}
//DETECTAR PULSACION DE BACK

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
      .setTitle("Salir")
      .setMessage("Estás seguro?")
      .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)//sin listener
      .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {//un listener que al pulsar, cierre la aplicacion
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
          //Salir
            System.exit(0);
        }
      })
      .show();

    // Si el listener devuelve true, significa que el evento esta procesado, y nadie debe hacer nada mas
    return true;
  }
//para las demas cosas, se reenvia el evento al listener habitual
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
} 

public void login(View view){
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }catch(Exception e){
        //AL COMPROBAR Q EL SCANNER NO ESTA INSTALADO, LO INSTALA
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No se encuentra ZScanner, se procede a instalar la app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
        startActivity(marketIntent);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


//RESULTADO DEL SCANNER FUERA DE LA ASYNC
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

     if (requestCode == 0) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             resultadoqr= intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
             //String formato = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
             // Hacer algo con los datos obtenidos.
             //resultado.setText(contenido);
             if (resultadoqr != null) {
                // Quiere decir que se obtuvo resultado por lo tanto:       
                 pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 Log.e("==>","Comenzando peticion: "+resultadoqr);
                 new MyAsyncTask().execute(resultadoqr);
            } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usuario no encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
            }

         } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
             // Si se cancelo la captura.
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "El escaneo ha sido cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             toast.show();
         }
     }
}


// CLASE ASYNC DE LOG ON

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



         @Override
          protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(resultadoqr);
            return null;

          }

         protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
             pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Peticion enviada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             //TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre);
             //t.setText(texto);
             if(texto.length()<1){
                    // out of range
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario Erróneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }else if (texto==null){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error desconocido, contacte con el soporte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido usuario "+texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "¿Qué desea?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent ("com.oceanapps.bagu.PanelProductosActivity");
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }


         }
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){
             pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
         }

        public void postData(String valorAEnviar) {

            Log.e("==>","Accediendo a php");
            try {
                String postReceiverUrl = "http://miqueas.segeon.es/posts/post_usuario.php";
                // HttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                // add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario", valorAEnviar));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // execute HTTP post request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                if (resEntity != null) {

                    String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                    texto = responseStr; 
                    // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
                }


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // process execption
            }catch(Exception ex) { 
                Log.e("ERROR", ex.toString());
            }

        }
    }
```

}

And here is the error.

```
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at com.oceanapps.bagu.LoginActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:176)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at com.oceanapps.bagu.LoginActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
05-31 13:38:42.117: E/AndroidRuntime(8273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The PHP documents is Ok, tested and it runs.

Somebody could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please, spot which line is `LoginActivity.java:176`

Comment: What is  `pb`? and where you `initialized` it?

Comment: Exception happening at Linenumber 176 in `LoginActivity.java`

Comment: its pb(ProgressBar) that is not initialized.

Comment: Sorry guys, Im gonna edit my post to show all the code. PB is a progress bar.

Comment: The line 176 its the if whem I said :if(texto.length()<1){

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without knowing which line is throwing the exception, but chances are that `pb` or `texto` variables are `null`. Please, double check you're setting them to appropriate values before running the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

In the following bit of code, you should check if the `texto` variable is null as the first conditional statement, so that texto.length() is only called if texto is not null.

Change this:

```
         if(texto.length()<1){
                // out of range
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario Erróneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }else if (texto==null){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error desconocido, contacte con el soporte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido usuario "+texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "¿Qué desea?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent ("com.oceanapps.bagu.PanelProductosActivity");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
```

To this:

```
         if (texto==null){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error desconocido, contacte con el soporte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else if(texto.length()<1){
                // out of range
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario Erróneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else{
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido usuario "+texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "¿Qué desea?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent i = new Intent ("com.oceanapps.bagu.PanelProductosActivity");
             startActivity(i);
             finish();
            }
```

Comment: I'll get texto= null cause that code:
// execute HTTP post request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
Doesnt work and i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

You defined a String object with the following code:

```
public String texto;
```

but you never initialized the variable with a value. A String class is a nullable which means it can be NULL. At the following line you use this variable while it hasn't been initialized anywhere in your code.

```
if(texto.length()<1){
```

This is where java throws a NULLPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Texto (String you made, but no initiate) is reason of the crash.

Before you check the length of Texto, you should check whether if null or not at the first of your logic.

Example

```
 if (text == null) {

} else if (text.length < 1) { 

} else ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is Nullpointer and its in OnPostExecute its apparent that it can be either due to `pb` the progressBar object or the `textto` the string but it cannot be pb because just before you are calling AsyncTask you called pb hence it should be fine therefore the only reason i guess is due to `textto` So i will go step by step for fixing the issue...

Method 1. replace this with `public String texto;` with `public String texto="Error";`
Method 2. Use this class [ConnectionClass.java](http://pixfiesta.com/wordpress/ConnectionClass.java) instead for http connection ( i have changed the code a bit for your specific case else this class is for general use ).

Now tweak the async class code like this :-

```
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{



         @Override
          protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
   ConnectionClass cc=new ConnectionClass(LoginActivity.this);
   return cc.connectToServer("http://miqueas.segeon.es/posts/post_usuario.php",resultadoqr);


          }

         protected void onPostExecute(String result){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Peticion enviada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             //t.setText(texto);
             if(result!=""){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido usuario "+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "¿Qué desea?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent ("com.oceanapps.bagu.PanelProductosActivity");
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
             }

else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error desconocido, contacte con el soporte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

         }
```

Also check if INTERNET permission is given in the manifest and also check if you can connect to the net when using app...

One more thing i executed miqueas.segeon.es/posts/post_usuario.php?usuario=tester but the response is blank so do check that too...

Try out above thing i have tried to debugg the issue if it helps and hope it helps do let us know... :)

thx